# VS - Show more than one Diff window

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, tfs, diff

In Visual Studio, e.g. VS2012, how do I show more than one `Diff` window, e.g. when doing compare operations in TFS?

[image]

So, rather than re-using this `Diff` tab, it simply opens one for every compare operation you perform and you would need to close them when finished.

Comment: Sorry guy, I made a mistake. I have found something new. This could be achieved, have updated my answer. Please check it.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to click the button **keep open** (on the top right corner) in the opened diff window.
[image]

This will open a new tab in VS just as below screenshot. Even though I'm working on VS2015. According to your picture(also with this button). I think this should also work with VS2012.
[image]